# Equality in distribution for order statistic from symmetric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have $\{X_1, \dots ,X_n\}$ which are IID samples from a continuous distribution with
CDF $F$. Furthermore, the density is symmetric about some $\mu$. Now we wish to show that for any $r$, this equality in distribution holds
\begin{equation}
 X_{(n-r+1)} - \mu \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} \mu - X_{(r)}, 
\end{equation}
where we denote the $r$:th ordinal statistic of $X$: $X_{(r)}$. We also know that the density of the $r$:th order statistic is given by
\begin{equation} 
f_{(r)}(u)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} F^{r-1}(u)(1-F(u))^{n-r}f(u).
\end{equation}
Hence, we know that the distribution of $X_{(n-r+1)}$ corresponds to
\begin{equation} 
f_{(n-r+1)}(u)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} F^{n-r}(u)(1-F(u))^{r-1}f(u).
\end{equation}
My initial approach was to express the CDF of $Y_1 = X_{(n-r+1)} - \mu $ and $Y_2 = \mu - X_{(r)}$ according to
\begin{equation} 
P(Y_1\leq y_1) = P(X_{(n-r+1)} - \mu \leq y_1) = P(X_{(n-r+1)} \leq y_1 + \mu) = F_{(n-r+1)}(y_1+\mu),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
P(Y_2\leq y_2) = P(\mu - X_{(r)} \leq y_2) = P(\mu - y_2\leq X_{(r)}) = 1 - P(X_{(r)} \leq  \mu - y_2) = 1- F_{(r)}(\mu-y_2) = F_{(r)}(\mu+y_2),
\end{equation}
where symmetry around $\mu$ was used in the last step. My idea was now to express these CDFs in integral form and then after a change of variable involving $\mu$ being able to identify that the densities of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are analogous. However, I attain that
\begin{equation} 
 F_{(n-r+1)}(\mu+y_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\mu+y_1} f_{(n-r+1)}(u) du = \int_{-\infty}^{y_1} f_{(n-r+1)}(x-\mu) dx  \propto  \int_{-\infty}^{y_1} F^{n-r}(x-\mu)(1-F(x_\mu))^{r-1}f(x -\mu) dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
 F_{(r)}(\mu+y_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{\mu+y_2} f_{(r)}(u) du = \int_{-\infty}^{y_2} f_{(r)}(x-\mu) dx  \propto  \int_{-\infty}^{y_2} F^{r-1}(x-\mu)(1-F(x-\mu))^{n-r}f(x-\mu) dx.
\end{equation}
And when comparing these CDFs I can't seem to equate the expression inside the integrant, on the account of the CDF $F$ having different exponents for $F$ and $(1-F)$.

Any pointers regarding my approach or other suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach / I didn't work out all the details...

The fundamental insight behind the equality is that $X - \mu$ and $\mu - X$ are identically distributed, because $F()$ is symmetric about $\mu$, which incidentally translates to $F(\mu + u) = 1 - F(\mu - u)$.

IMHO there should be no need to work with the CDFs of the order statistics.  Why don't you try working with the given PDFs directly?  Using $F(\mu + u) = 1 - F(\mu - u)$ you might be able to directly prove the PDFs are equal.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Oh gosh, I am so tired and error-prone.  :( Thanks again!